# Draw circle on click in canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Hi I'm trying to create a code that draws a circle when a user clicks on the canvas element. So when a user clicks on the canvas element a circle is drawn within canvas.

```js
var canvas =document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');


var putLeaves = function() {
c.beginPath();
c.arc(300,300,30,0,Math.PI*2,false);
c.fillStyle ="#d57b85"
c.fill
}

canvas.addEventListner('mousedown', putLeaves)
```

```css
#canvas{
position: absolute;
left: 44%;
top: 15%;
margin: 0;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: First fix typos. `addEventListner` is misspelled. And then draw circle inside visible area of canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use Element.getBoundingClientRect method found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

```
<script>
var canvas =document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');


var putLeaves = function(e) {
  var bounds = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = e.clientX - bounds.left;
  var y = e.clientY - bounds.top;

  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(x,y,30,0,Math.PI*2,false);
  c.fillStyle ="#d57b85"
  c.fill
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', putLeaves)
</script>
```